# Best MySQL Database Structure for a Yellow Pages Site

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

Im building a yellow pages site. I tried multiple database structures. Im not sure which one is best. Here are few I considered,

1. Saving all business data - name, phone, email etc in one table, list of tags in another, and mapping data id and tag id for tag-data relationship in a third table. I found this cumbersome since I'll be doing most things directly in the database (at least initially, before launch) and hence distributing everything can be problematic in my case. This one is a clean solution I must admit though.
2. Saving biz entries in one table with a separate column for tags (that'll contain comma separated(or JSON) tags for every entry). Then retrieving results using like query or full-text search for a tag. This one will be slower and will get more slow as db size increases. Also its not easy to maintain - suppose if I have to rename a tag.
3. **(My Preferred Choice)** Distributing biz data in different tables based on type - all banks in one, hotels, restaurants etc in separate tables. A separate table for all tags containing a rule for searching data from the table. Here is a detailed explanation.

**Biz Tables:**
college_tbl, bank_tbl, hotel_tbl, restaurant_tbl...so on

**Tags Table**

```
ID | Biz Table      | Tag Name              | Tag Key         | Match Rule (col:like_query_part)
1  | bank_tbl       | Citi Bank Branches    | ['citi','bank'] | 'name:%$1%$2%'
2  | restaurant_tbl | Pizza Hut Restaurants | ['pizza','hut'] | 'name:%$1%$2%'
3  | hotel_tbl      | The Leela Hotels      | ['the leela']   | 'name:%$1%'
```

I'll then use 'Match rule' in like query to fetch results from 'Biz Table' for 'Tag Name'.

Im going forward with the third approach. I feel its simple, reduces the need of third data-tag relationship table, renaming is easy and performance won't get down if table has limited entries - say 1 million max per table.

Im scratching my head for the last 15 days to find the best structure and feel this one is pretty good in my case.

**Please suggest a better approach or if this approach could have some issues later on.**

Comment: Why third point is out when entries are limited. Support your point with some valid reason. I'm doing trials and don't think it a very bad idea.

Comment: i would just say that it all (typically) comes down to your experience. all three of them could work, but at the same time all three of them are probably poor approaches to efficient schemas. but unless you have the skills to make the advanced queries, why complicate the hell out of things for yourself. sql efficient is dictated by sql knowledge.

Comment: So what should be the best approach.

Comment: The best approach is to read a couple of articles on database normalization.

Comment: I'm not using the second one, first one is probably the best approach but if you look at the third one, it really reduces work by a lot. And if you just keep data size to a level that like query performs well then what's the issue. I'm open to changes, just looking for an approach that's simple and good in performance.

Comment: I've done my research before asking this question. Even those articles say use this or that approach. I understand normalization for your information. Its just I'm trying something that I think would work pretty well in my case. As Im saying, Im open to a new idea, give me if you have one @e4c5. Give an answer, clue or a something to help rather than just directing me to do research.

Comment: Normalization may not be important in this application.

Answer (score 0):

Use Number 1.  Period, full stop.

The mistake is "doing things directly in the database" rather than developing the API first.

Number 2 has one advantage -- `FULLTEXT` search.  That can be tacked onto #1 after you have have a working API and some data to play with.

Number 3 (multiple similar tables) is a fisaco. *Numerous* Q&A ask about such; the reply is always "NO".

Comment: [_Tips on many:many table_](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/4857/many-to-many-mapping-table).

Comment: Yes @rick, I too feel number 1 is the best approach. Point 2 and 3 aren't really the best way of using MySql and especially when data size will be big. Also like queries and FTS will hurt performance for sure.

Comment: Also I should first complete writing API first and work using that rather than coding in parts (to get desired operations done). Systematic approach is always better.

Comment: FTS _may_ be satisfactorily fast.  But keep in mind the limitations (min word len, etc).